# Cómo saber el tipo de dato de un puntero void

Tags: c

Supongamos que tengo un puntero `void` el cual, dependiendo del caso, le asignaré un `char*` o `int` o `double` o `bool`, etc. Cómo puedo determinar el tipo de dato enlazado al puntero?

Por ejemplo en `goLang` es algo así:

```
switch v := i.(type) {
case T:
    // here v has type T
case S:
    // here v has type S
default:
    // no match; here v has the same type as i
}
```

¿Cómo podría hacer algo similar en C no C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No puedes. Sólo con el puntero no se puede saber el tipo del dato al que apunta. Necesitas esa información en algún otro lugar (otro parámetro de la función, por ejemplo).

Un truco típico para evitar ese parámetro adicional suele ser el siguiente.

Se definen una serie de estructuras similares, todas ellas con un primer campo de tamaño prefijado (ej `char`), y luego ya los restantes campos los que sean. Ese primer campo guardará un valor que servirá para diferenciar qué tipo de estructura particular es la que sigue.

De ese modo la función puede comenzar por hacer un *casting* a una de estas estructuras (se puede definir incluso una especie de "clase base abstracta" que tendría sólo el primer campo) y así podrá acceder al "discriminante" (el campo que le dice de qué tipo es). Según el valor de ese discriminante ya se puede hacer después un casting al tipo adecuado para poder acceder a los restantes campos.

Esta sería una demostración de la idea:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct AbstractBaseClass {
    char tipo;
};

struct Entero {
    char tipo;
    int dato;
};

struct Double {
    char tipo;
    double dato;
};

void prueba(void *p) {
    struct Entero *p_e;
    struct Double *p_d; 

    switch(((struct AbstractBaseClass*)p)->tipo) {
        case 1:  // Entero
            p_e  = (struct Entero*) p;
            printf("El dato entero vale %d\n", p_e->dato);
            break;
        case 2:  // Double
            p_d = (struct Double*) p;
            printf("El dato double vale %f\n", p_d->dato);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Dato de tipo desconocido\n");
    }
}


int main()
{
    struct Entero *pe = malloc(sizeof(struct Entero));
    struct Double *pd = malloc(sizeof(struct Double));

    pe->tipo = 1;
    pe->dato = 100;
    pd->tipo = 2;
    pd->dato = 3.1415;

    prueba((void*) pe);
    prueba((void*) pd);
    pe->tipo = 3;
    prueba((void*) pe);
    return 0;
}
```

Produce al ejecutarse:

```
El dato entero vale 100
El dato double vale 3.141500
Dato de tipo desconocido
```

**Observa** que es responsabilidad del programador (el código de main) el asignar correctamente y coherentemente el valor del discriminante. Nada nos impide declarar un puntero a `Entero`, guardar un entero en el campo `.dato` y en cambio poner un 2 en el campo `.tipo`. Obviamente las funciones que reciban un dato así no funcionarán correctamente pues castearán al tipo incorrecto e interpretarán incorrectamente los bytes del campo `dato` de la estructura.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has dado una luz con tu ejemplo.